# How to calculate an average stock price depending on periods

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I am trying to calculate the average opening price for a stock, depending on different periods (week, month, year).

Here you can see a part of my df : [My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jREi7.png) (987 rows for the complete df)

Firstly, I am trying to calculate the average opening price week by week. I found a solution, but it is unsustainable (it took my computer 5min to finish the calculations). Here it is :

```
def average_opening_and_closing_prices(df):
    
    array = [0]
    n = df["weekofyear"].count()
    j=0

    for i in range(0,n): 

        array[j] = array[j] + kdf["Open"][i]
        if i != n-1 and kdf["weekofyear"][i] != kdf["weekofyear"][i+1]:
            array.append(0)
            j = j+1
    
    for x in array:
      print(str(x) + " ") 
    
average_opening_and_closing_prices(AMAZON_df)
```

Could you help me to improve my solution (mainly on execution time) ? Also, for example, I would like to add a column, directly to my df, which contains the results for each week, instead of putting the results in an array.

I am not allowed to use pandas, I can only use pyspark and koalas.

Comment: You need the average of the "open" column?

Comment: yes, I need the average for the "open" column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED: To include year into the calculation]
As you are looking for average price for week (and year) and already added the weekofyear in data frame, panda's itself can do it for you. Just add a column for year and try `df.groupby(['year', 'weekofyear']).mean()`
Sample below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weekofyear' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    'year' : [2017, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2018],
    'Open' : [757, 758, 759, 761, 761, 762, 763, 764, 764]
})

result_df = df.groupby(['year', 'weekofyear']).mean()

print(result_df)
```

Output

```
Open
year weekofyear       
2017 1           757.5
     2           761.0
     3           763.5
2018 1           759.0
     2           762.0
     3           764.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! The problem with your solution is that it mixes weeks from different years. As I said I have 987 rows, wich represent data for 4 years. 

So when I group by weekofyear, it groups week 1 from 2017, week 1 from 2018, week 1 from 2019. Therefore, the calculations are incorrect.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can add year column in DataFrame and then group by year and weekofyear and you get the result.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) But I have a question. Do you know how can I avoid problem like this : 2019-12-30 and 2019-12-31 are counted as week 1 for 2020. 
I know it is because week 1 starts with a monday, and the first day of 2020 is not a monday, so it tooks the begining of the week, which belong to 2019

Comment: Because now, when I groupby week and year, I will have the first week 1 for 2019, and a second week 1 which is at the end of 2019, and the will be grouped as one week 1

Comment: It's a separate problem then your question, but you can use strftime instead of weekofyear e.x. 
`df['week_format'] = df['date'].dt.strftime("%U")` instead of `df['weekofyear'] = df['date'].dt.weekofyear`

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
from statistics import mean 
average = mean([week["Open"] for week in df["weekofyear"]])
```

Search about "pythonic" for loop, loop over items and not indexes. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i tryed your solution, i got the error: PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.

Comment: I guess it is because your solution uses pandas and my df is a koalas df ?

Comment: try: `df = df.to_dict()`

Comment: I did it, i got : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable